# error al consultar datos

Tags: java

Hola estoy haciendo una consulta a una base de datos pero tengo un problema cuando este me devuelve el resultado, en la tabla de la base de datos a la que hago la consulta hay datos que incian con  este valor 00060306.1000 pero al hacer la consulta me regresa esto 636.1 es decir me esta quitando los ceros

esta es la parte donde estoy realizando eso

```
    public ParameterTable getCatalogoST(List<Map<String, Object>> listexecute){
   ParameterTable catalogoST = new ParameterTable(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"descripcionContocur"}));
   Iterator<Map<String, Object>> iterador = listexecute.iterator();

   while(iterador.hasNext()){
       Map<String, Object> newRow = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       newRow.put("descripcionContocur",iterador.next().get("MC04_CONTOCUR").toString().trim());//:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
       catalogoST.add(newRow);
       //LOGGER.info("### resultado  [" +catalogoST+ "]");////////prueba
   }

   return catalogoST;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por tomarse el tiempo de ayudar, les comento que ya soluciono el proble, y estaba pasando esto por incompatibilidad de versiones.

Answer (score 0):

El dato debe ser de tipo decimal en la base de datos y lo que te regresa es totalmente válido, ceros a la izquierda no valen. Lo que puedes hacer es rellenar de ceros los que te hagan falta con un formato.

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00000000.0000")
formatter.format(mi_decimal)
```

Comment: también esta borrándole los ceros que están entre números diferentes de cero y eso esta mal

Comment: Es verdad, ojala nos pueda dar más información sobre la tabla y el query.